# RateLimit Exception for Amazon IO Error while using filepicker REST to upload images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filepicker.io

I'm using filepicker's rest API to upload images, https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/rest/#blob-store

It was working fine for few uploads, then it started throwing the error - **RateLimit Exception for Amazon IO Error**

I think something wrong with amazon S3, any idea please ?

Comment: "something wrong with Amazon S3" seems unlikely.  How many uploads are you doing, per second, approximately?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Its max of 5 per second

Comment: I'm getting the same error at the moment. I'm talking to one of their support people. Will comment/answer back when I have an answer.

Comment: The reply, after a looooong wait, was that it's our S3 account that's at fault. The error is from Amazon but I think FP send back their own string, else I'd expect more than 10 results from Google!

Comment: Yeh, I guess this is kind of limitation from S3, I found it working very next day.